# How to set CPU architecture in APK for Google Play

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, apk, delphi-xe8

I have created an application for android in DELPHI XE8. If I want to publish it on Google Play and Google it shall be categorized device platforms ARMEABI, ARMEABI-V7A, MIPS and x86 while DELPHI XE8 (as well as all previous versions) only supports architecture ARMEABI-V7A.

***Do not come to me as a professional publishing application on Google Play that your application installs and someone will message to him that the platform is not supported.***

Analysis APK installation package generated DELPHI XE8 I discovered that it is automatically generated for all of the above platforms.

Google on its website (http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) recommends solutions using Android NDK - unfortunately, I still could not figure out how to do that ...

As another solution is recommended to read and edit ANDROID.mk (unfortunately, this file does not generate DELPHI XE8).

**The question is how to achieve that DELPHI XE8 compiled APK file *only for ARMEABI-V7A*?**

**Anyone have any experience or a solution to this problem?**

Comment: I have the same problem. Another possibility is when recording each new version of the file on Google Play APK hand-selection of supported devices ... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found a solution and it's very simple and plain:

Simply in DELPHI XE8 menu Project -> Deployment (section RELEASE CONFIGURATION - ANDROID PLATFORM) uncheck these items:

1. $(BDS)\lib\android\Release\x86\
2. $(BDS)\lib\android\Release\mips\
3. $(BDS)\lib\android\Release\armeabi\

and let checked this item

4. Android\Release\  (remote path is library\lib\armeabi-v7a)

perform **Build application** and then **Deploy**.

**From now on Google Play displays only supported devices to the native platform ARMEABI-V7A.**

Comment: It's really very simple. ;)

Comment: Makes one wonder why these options even exist in the configuration since Delphi does not support those architectures yet.

Comment: You're right. So far, it is useless. But perhaps the programmers at Embarcadero forward thinking. And they know what we do not yet.

Comment: They added them I assume because people complained that the app would launch as blank or just close in older versions on unsupported hardware. Now it gives you a message on unsupported hardware so you know why it doesn't run. And it's also possible Google Play originally didn't have an architecture filter 1-2 years ago.

Comment: My guess is this way you can create your own x86/mips/armeabi version of your app (in any other compiler), either fully working (not likely) or with customized messages about why it doesn't work, add it to the respective folder (release\x86; release\mips; release\armeabi), and Delphi will deploy it in a single apk.

Could be wrong though!